# Laravel query Builder in key/value pair

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a table to store ticket's labels. I have saved multiple labels as comma(,) separated string in value column.

```
+----+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | ticket_id | key   | value         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  9 |        22 | label | Important,Bug | 2016-10-10 14:48:07 | 2016-10-10 14:48:07 |
| 17 |        21 | label |               | 2016-10-10 16:46:13 | 2016-10-10 16:46:13 |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Now I have to search the labels and get the associated ticket_id, My search terms is an array

```
array:1 [
  0 => "Important"
]
```

Please help me to write a query

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that:

```
$query = Model::where('value','like','%' . $array[0] . '%');

for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $query->orWhere('value','like','%' . $array[i] . '%');
}

return $query->get();
```

Warning, the first `where` method is only necessary after the 5.3 release. Before it, you may directly begin by an `orWhere` clause.

> Eloquent scopes now respect the leading boolean of scope constraints.
>   For example, if you are starting your scope with an orWhere constraint
>   it will no longer be converted to normal where. If you were relying on
>   this feature (e.g. adding multiple orWhere constraints within a loop),
>   you should verify that the first condition is a normal where to avoid
>   any boolean logic issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But it is giving two row value but it should only give one raw.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter = new Filter();
$query = $filter->where('key', 'label')
                ->where(function($query) use($labels) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($labels); $i++) {
                        $query->orWhere('value', 'LIKE', '%' . $labels[$i] . '%');
                    }
                })
                ->get();

return $query;
```